# What is the "Athena database" in the Cloudformation AWS::Athena::NamedQuery template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena

In the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-athena-namedquery.html) for `AWS::Athena::NamedQuery` we have a lovely YAML,

```
Resources:
  AthenaNamedQuery:
    Type: AWS::Athena::NamedQuery
    Properties:
      Database: "swfnetadata"
      Description: "A query that selects all aggregated data"
      Name: "MostExpensiveWorkflow"
      QueryString: >
                    SELECT workflowname, AVG(activitytaskstarted) AS AverageWorkflow
                    FROM swfmetadata
                    WHERE year='17' AND GROUP BY workflowname
                    ORDER BY AverageWorkflow DESC LIMIT 10
```

But what is `Database: "swfnetadata"`? Where/how do I define that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Athena tables can only exist within databases.

From the docs:

> Athena uses Apache Hive to define tables and create databases, which
>   are essentially a logical namespace of tables. When you create a
>   database and table in Athena, you are simply describing the schema and
>   where the table data are located in Amazon S3 for read-time querying.

So in your case, you have to state the database where the table was created in.

[Creating Databases and Tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/creating-tables.html)

Comment: How do I create an Apache Hive database in Cloudformation?

Comment: It [almost looks like](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/aws-cloudformation-features-update-support-for-amazon-athena-coverage-updates-for-s3-rds-kinesis-and-cloudwatch/) you don't need a database and using `default` will work fine

Answer (score 1):

Cloudformation snippet to create an Athena database, which is a Glue database.

```
Parameters:
  DatabaseName:
    Type: String
    Default: dev_db
Resources:
 # Create an AWS Glue database
  MyDevAthenaDatabase:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Database
    Properties:
      # The database is created in the Data Catalog for your account
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      DatabaseInput:
        # The name of the database is defined in the Parameters section above
        Name: !Ref DatabaseName
        Description: Database to hold dev tables
# Create tables
  MyGlueTable1:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Table
    DependsOn: MyDevAthenaDatabase
```